# Java - List to HashMap<Long,Set<String>>

Tags: java, drop-down-menu, hashmap, set

Hi guys need some help with HashMaps and Sets, i`m new to this.

Basically i`m getting a List of ArrayList for the db and need to populate 2(two) dropdownlists. Based on the first dropdownlist selection I need to popluate the second dropdownlist.

```
List<Placement> list = (ArrayList<Placement>) placementrepos.findAll();
```

list =  [0]...[7]

```
         (id, name, date)   
    [0] = 1, Jack, 2000
    [1] = 2, Mary, 2002
    [2] = 3, John, 2008
    ...
    [7] = 8, Jack, 2010
```

So the the first dropdownlist need to list the unique names :
Jack, Mary, John

and the second dropdownlist(if Jack was selected) :
2000, 2010

Comment: `Map<Name, List<Date>>` is what you need. Name would be String and date might be integer representing year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Something like this**:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> customMap = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();

for(Placement p: list) {
    customeMap.put(p.getName(), p.getYear())
}
```

...considering `Year` is an `Integer`.

After that, you can store each `Map` in a `List` (list of maps) and pull from there.